# What is the relationship between spectral resolution and spectral measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

In Kadison and Ringrose's book "FUNDAMENTALS OF THE THEORY
OF OPERATOR ALGEBRAS", the author gives the following theorem.

Theorem: If $A$ is a self-adjoint operator acting on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ and $\mathscr{A}$ is an abelian von Neumann algebra containing $A$, there is a family $\{E_\lambda\}$ of projections, indexed by $\mathbb{R}$, in $\scr{A}$ such that

(1) $E_\lambda=0$ if $\lambda<-\|A\|$ and $E_\lambda=I$ if $\lambda\geq\|A\|$;

(2) $E_\lambda\leq E_{\lambda'}$ if $\lambda\leq\lambda'$;

(3) $E_\lambda=\wedge_{\lambda'>\lambda}E_{\lambda'}$;

(4) $AE_\lambda\leq\lambda E_\lambda$ and $A(I-E_\lambda)\leq\lambda(I-E_\lambda)$;

(5) $A=\int^{\|A\|}_{-\|A\|}\lambda dE_\lambda$ in the sense of norm convergence of approximating
Riemann sums; and $A$ is the norm limit of finite linear combinations with
coefficients in $sp(A)$ of orthogonal projections $E_{\lambda'}-E_\lambda$.

I want to know what (3) means and also what is the relationship between such so called "spectral resolution" $E_\lambda$ and the spectral measure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula connecting the spectral resolution of $E_{\lambda}$ and the spectral measure $E$ is $E_\lambda=E((-\infty,\lambda]),\ \mbox{for all}\  \lambda\in\mathbb R.$ You can get $E$ from $E_\lambda$ by setting $E((a,b]):=E_b-E_a$ etc.

Condition (3) means $E_\lambda$ is the greatest lower bound of $E_{\lambda'},\ \lambda'>\lambda.$ Equivalently, $E_\lambda$ is the strong limit of $E_{\lambda'},\ \lambda'\to\lambda+0.$

Comment: Thank you! The spectral measure $E$ is continuous? But why to find a family $\{E_\lambda\}$ such that (3) hold? What's the benefit to do so?

Comment: Very often the spectral theorem is stated as in (5). The reason is that $E_\lambda$ is easier to construct then $E$. You just need to carefully define the function $\chi_{(-\infty,\lambda]}(A),$ which can be done with continuous functional calculus.

Comment: Evenif (3) is not hold, we can also construct a spectral measure $E$ corresponding to $\{E_\lambda\}$. Now with (3) hold, is it brings some good properties to $E$?

Comment: You need (3) to prove that $E((-\infty,\lambda]):=E_\lambda$ satisfies the countable additivity ("good property").

Comment: Is (3) equivalent to the countable additivity?

Comment: I would not use the word "equivalent". Condition (3) for $E_\lambda$ implies countable additivity of E and countable additivity of E implies (3).